# "Array sizes are inconsistent" error while using array_multisort

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array by multiple values but I keep getting the error:

`Warning: array_multisort() [function.array-multisort]: Array sizes are inconsistent in` -- `on line 19`

Line 19 is where I call the array_multisort function:

`array_multisort($column1, $column2, $column3, $row);`

I have been unable to replicate the issue in a test, so I haven't had much luck in solving the issue.

So basically I am saving a MySql table as a multidimensional associative array. Then I am trying to sort the rows by three different columns. I have checked and all of the arrays passed into the `array_multisort()` function are the same size. I checked both by manually looking through every row and by using `sizeof()`.

Any ideas what could be causing this and/or what the solution is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended just using `uasort()` instead. it gave me no problems at all and it was pretty straight forward to set up the cmp logic.

Still no idea what the issue with `array_multisort()` was.

Answer (score 7):

to answer your original question, this normally happens with an uninitiated variable. 
For example:

```
foreach ($arr_this_referers as $int_key => $arr_row) {
    $arr_vol[$int_key]  = $arr_row['int_cnt'];
}
```

will cause WARNING due to uninitiated variable $arr_vol but initialize variable before the for loop:

```
$arr_vol = array();
foreach ($arr_this_referers as $int_key => $arr_row) {
    $arr_vol[$int_key]  = $arr_row['int_cnt'];
}
array_multisort($arr_vol, SORT_DESC, $arr_this_referers);
```

... & warning disappears, hope this helps.